# How do i do a partial match on integers using bindingsource.find method?

Tags: vb.net

please assist, I am new to vb.net and working on a project while I'm learning. I am trying to find index/location of a value in a gridview. When I search for a value I want to be able to find the exact value or next available value as well as values less and greater than that value. These are sizes of products of a manufacturing company so if I search for 10 and it is not available I should be able to see what is available which could be 9.1 or 11 as these may work for the project and if 10 is available then great. below if the code below which is only allowing me to find exact value. If I search for 10 which the value is 10.1 it does not find it. I tried using LIKE and it did not work because I am working with numbers. I am stuck now. Datasource of data binding is DataTable and database is ms access.  idsize column is type double.if searched value is not there it can find the next available value without considering range.

```
TblDiesBindingSource.Position = TblDiesBindingSource.Find("IDSIZE", TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: What is the underlying DataSource of your BindingSource? What is the actual Type of the `IDSIZE` Column? -- What can be considered *close enough* to the starting value, to still represent a valid result? Is there a specific range? -- You can use `BETWEEN` in a filter (the data Type of the Column becomes more important).

Comment: hi, the data type is double and range closest value if actual value is not available could be 0.01. my data source is ms access database. sorry im just realizing i left out a lot of information. i hope this is enough.

Comment: *if I search for 10 and it is not available I should be able to see what is available which could be 9.1 or 11* and *closest value if actual value is not available could be 0.01* don't match.

Comment: Also, your source of data is not an Access database, that's your storage medium. You have to specify the DataSource of the BindingSource (e.g., a DataTable, other collection of objects, a class Model etc.) -- Add all the information you have, as precise as possible, to the body of question, not in comments.